# How to setup a UIScrollView to arrange content dynamically?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a user profile screen. The screen will have lots of information about a user. It will look similar to this AirB

[image]

From the looks of it, it seems to be some sort of scrollView? or is it a tableView or a collectionView? (because it seems that there are some rows in there i think)

Does any one here know how this type of view can be accomplished or can be setup?

**EDIT** two answers below says to use a UITableview, and 2 other answers says to avoid it. Are there any benefits/disadvantages to using either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only one child `UIView` as i will call it `ContainerView` inside `UIScrollView` and then place your child views inside that `ContainerView`. Use constraint to trailing and leading and top and bottom of that `ContainerView` to `UIScrollView`. and use constraint for placing child views to viewController.view not to `ContainerView` to then iOS will find where child views have to be.

[Good Tutorial to find out how to use constraint on scrollView](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/)

[Apple Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)

Comment: i used a combination of UIScoll view and UITableView. I embedded the tableView inside the scrollview. So the scrollview contained some views, plus a uitableView plus others views. They were arrainged in the scrollview using UIStackViews

Answer (score 1):

Do Not use tableview in this case, this content is difficult to maintain in a table view, really, use a scrollview, as for how, a simple googling for "swift uiscrollview tutorial"

Answer (score 0):

Tableview is the best solution for this kind of scrolling views but in the screen you have mapview if it updates every moment i.e. updates with current location then it is not recommended to use tableview.

In that case you can use scrollview with custom views add subview changing with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my app i did same thing using Tableview. And for that tableview i created a custom cell which have such a big height and i added all the images,map,details of user in that. And it work similar to what you want.
If you want help reply to my answer